# How to work Xamarin with SQL Server using Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am trying to connect to SQL Server with Xamarin using Web API, but I don't know somehow I am doing something wrong here is my code,

Webapi controller

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    UserEntities db = new UserEntities();  

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("XAMARIN_REG")]
    // POST: api/Login  
    public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_reg(string username, string password)
    {
        Login login = new Login();
        login.username = username;
        login.password = password;
        db.Logins.Add(login);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Successfully Created");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("XAMARIN_Login")]
    // GET: api/Login/5  
    public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = db.Logins.Where(x => x.username == username && x.password == password).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Please Enter valid UserName and Password");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Success");
        }
    }

}
```

xamarin Activity

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

    EditText txtusername;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btncreate;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create your application here  
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        txtusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtsaveusername);
        txtPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtsavepassword);
        btncreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnsavecreate);

        btncreate.Click += Btncreate_Click;
    }
    private async void Btncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login log = new Login();
        log.username = txtusername.Text;
        log.password = txtPassword.Text;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "http://localhost:54445/api/Login/";
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            var errorMessage1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\\", "").Trim(new char[1]
            {
            '"'
            });
            Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage1, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            var errorMessage1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\\", "").Trim(new char[1]
            {
            '"'
            });
            Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage1, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

i want to work on local sql server not with azure,
 this code should save username and password to my local sql server, but when i click on button to save its give me this error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request
```

Comment: Please don't roll your own authentication -- authentication is difficult to do in a safe, secure way. There are any number of readily available authentication frameworks you can use.

Comment: i know,i just wana test to save any data in database this is only for testing purpose

Comment: First, use a tool like Postman to test your WebApi so you can rule out any problems in that layer vs. your client layer.  Second, don't use localhost.  Use the IP or FQDN of your server.

Comment: i have tested with postman its not working there as well and how to use ip or fqdn?

Comment: I have also tested to run webapi in postman tool i am getting this error

`{
    "$id": "1",
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54445/api/Login'.",
    "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Login' that matches the request."
}`

Comment: Edit WebApiConfig.cs file ,

Change routeTemplete as like this,
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Answer (score 0):

Edit your WebApiConfig.cs File & Change the Route Template as like this,

> routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Hope it works.

Comment: I already tried this url i am getting this error

`{
    "$id": "1",
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54445/api/Login'.",
    "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Login' that matches the request."
}`